# How to know if user's email is already registered

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I'm using FirebaseAuth to create an user account, but I want to know if the user is already registered, to alert the user what's happening.

I've seen posts about this from April but it seems like **addOnCompleteListener** doesn't exists anymore.

Is there another way to implement this?

Here's what I have:

```
try {
  final newUser = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: _email, password: _password);
  if (newUser != null) 
    Navigator.pushNamed(context, HomePage.id);
} catch (e) {...}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FirebaseAuth's createUserWithEmailAndPassword function will return an exception if there is already an account associated with that email, and for any other error that happens during signup. You can listen for this exception and act accordingly. The way I usually do this is in an async function in a seperate Auth service class:

Async Function Example:

```
Future<String> signUp(String email, String password) async {
    AuthResult result = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: email, password: password);
    return result.user.uid;
  }
```

Await for result:

```
try {
        await signUp(email, password).then((uid) {
          // User successfully created so Navigate to new page etc
        });
      } catch (e) {
        print("Error in sign up: $e");
        String exception = getExceptionText(e);
        _showErrorAlert(
          title: "Signup failed",
          content: exception,
        );
      }
```

And for reference here is the getExceptionText function inside the Auth service:

```
String getExceptionText(Exception e) {
    if (e is PlatformException) {
      switch (e.message) {
        case 'There is no user record corresponding to this identifier. The user may have been deleted.':
          return 'User with this e-mail not found.';
          break;
        case 'The password is invalid or the user does not have a password.':
          return 'Invalid password.';
          break;
        case 'A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred.':
          return 'No internet connection.';
          break;
        case 'The email address is already in use by another account.':
          return 'Email address is already taken.';
          break;
        default:
          return 'Unknown error occured.';
      }
    } else {
      return 'Unknown error occured.';
    }
  }
```

Comment: Such a great answer, I'm really thankful!! @Jwildsmith

Answer (score 4):

To know if an account already exists in Firebase Authentication for a given email address, call the [`fetchSignInMethodsForEmail` method](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/FirebaseAuth/fetchSignInMethodsForEmail.html). The logic of this method is that it'll tell you with what provider(s) an account was created for that email address, so that you can show a UI allowing the user to pick their provider.